# How can i stop bootstrap 4 tooltip on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 tooltip this is working fine but when i hover on tooltip black box this should not hide, how can i do this?

My Code:

```css
 .tooltip-inner {max-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden;}
    ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box{ width: 300px;}
    ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box::after{ content: ''; display: table; clear: both;}
    ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box li{ list-style: none; text-align: left;}
    ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box li span{ width: 50%; float: left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container p-5">
 <p class="float-right mb-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="
                                        <ul class='trading-rules-tooltip-box'>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <a href='#' class='float-left'>View More</a>
                                        ">  Trading Rules</p>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Right now i'm unable to click on view more button which is inside the tooltip box, how can i fix it?

Comment: Tooltips are not meant for that, try to use popovers.

Comment: Popovers would be the right way, but if you still wish to use tooltip you may use trigger properties of tooltip

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip is working as expected. It's working the same as the Bootstrap 4 example. If you want the tooltip content visible, will you consider to change the `<p>` tag to `<button>`? So that when the user click on the button, the tooltip content will hold.

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 100% !important;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box {
  width: 300px;
}

ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box::after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

ul.trading-rules-tooltip-box li span {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container p-5">
    <button class="float-right mb-0" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" title="
                                        <ul class='trading-rules-tooltip-box'>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                            <li><span>Minimum Trade Amount</span> <span>0.000000 BTC</span></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <a href='#' class='float-left'>View More</a>
                                        "> Trading Rules</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i just need to click on view more button not on the trading rules and other UL list etc...

Comment: you may add delay to hide the tooltip content. But, the tooltip content will only close after the delay you set.

Answer (score 0):

This is basic exexcution of tooltip. you can use popover to achieve same functionality. 
Please check below url for more detail
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap navbar to achieve same functionality.
If you like to use navbar please to this link.
[Bootstrap navbar dropdown on hover](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=make-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-on-hover)